# YARN Fair-Scheduler do not put job on pending state

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, hadoop-yarn, scheduler

I am facing with an issue related to the fair scheduler of YARN. (Hadoop 3.2.2)

I have a set of jobs let's say 6 that are all submitted to a "specific_queue".
Within this queue, at most 2 jobs could run in parallel, and i would like that the other 4 stay in a Pending/Accepted state.

However, with the current configuration i am able to the 2 jobs in parallel and the other 4 results as "Pending Application", but within YARN their state is in RUNNING and no resource are allocated to them (as it should be).

Since within my jobs there is a restartable policy after some minutes this cause that since their state is "RUNNING" (and so active) they reach the related maximun restart attempt that i configured, but no operations are done within them.

Is there a way to explicity set the state to Pending/Accepted state and change it only if maxRunningApps is changed (decreades from 2 to 1 for instance)?

My fair-scheduler.xml is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<allocations>
 <queue name="specific_queue">
   <maxRunningApps>2</maxRunningApps>
 </queue>
 <queuePlacementPolicy>
  <rule name="default" queue="specific_queue"/>
 </queuePlacementPolicy>

 <queueMaxAppsDefault>2</queueMaxAppsDefault>
 <userMaxAppsDefault >2</userMaxAppsDefault >
</allocations>
```

I'm missing something within the fair-scheduler.xml?

This is what i saw within YARN.specific_queue
[image]

And this is the Jobs statuses as soon as the queue receive the jobs
[image]

Comment: May be you can try to set `maxAMShare` to something less than the default 0.5 (https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/FairScheduler.html#Allocation_file_format), and see whether it prevents applications exceeding your limit from going into running state because they can't allocate AM containers.

Comment: @mazaneicha thanks. The behaviour actually is the same. I decreased it until 0.1.

Comment: What does 0.1 translate into in terms of vcores?

Comment: @mazaneicha The same scenario as the picture, it gives 2 to the real running one and 0 to the other one. I do not know why it does in this way. If i was using hadoop 2 instead the queue manage the jobs in the right way but it never allocate the 100% of the cluster resources.